# Checkboxpreference change value

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, android-checkbox, preferencescreen

I have checkboxpreference in preference activity and I want that when one of the checkbox is enabled then other checkbox should get to disable and vice versa.
I wants to do that from my main class activity.

Here is my code:

Preferencecheckbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/img"
    android:key="check1"
    android:title="first" />
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/img2"
    android:key="check2"
    android:title="second" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Preferenceclass.java

```
public class preferenceclass extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferencecheckbox);
}
```

Comment: see `android:dependency` in `android.preference.Preference`

Comment: I dont think we can use radio button in preference screen

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a dependency to the checkbox you need disabled.

Like this:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/img2"
    android:key="check2"
    android:title="second" 
    android:dependency="check1" />
```

**Update**
To disable other preferences via code.

```
 final CheckBoxPreference checkbox2 = (CheakBoxPreference) findPreference("pref_checkbox2_key");

    CheckBoxPreference switch = (CheakBoxPreference) findPreference("pref_switch_key");
            switch.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    if (switch.isChecked()) {
                        checkbox2.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        checkbox2.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
    persistCheckBoxState(switch, checkbox2);
```

To persist the change when activity is closed, you need to get the preferences references like this and add directly below.

```
public void persistCheckBoxState (CheckBoxPreference switch, CheckBoxPreference checkbox2) {
if (switch.isChecked ()){ 
     checkbox2.setEnabled(false);
      } else {
      checkbox2.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: and what if there are more then 2 checkboxes then can we add 3 or more dependency to eachother

Comment: Yes. The `android:dependency` attribute uses the state of the referenced preference key to handle disabled or enabled state.

Comment: can you help me to do this programmatically.

Comment: its not working. I wants to uncheck all the checkbox when anyone of checkbox is checked

Comment: The snippets is working. Ensure you use your preferences key instead of mine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156527/discussion-between-codefreak-and-ravi).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a `ListPreference` is more what you want. From a usability point of view this would make more sense. When you have to choose one selection out of many this would be the most obvious way to do it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9881253/6868843) post for further instructions

Comment: well listprefernce works but I am not able to use image with it

Comment: well, that should not be a problem after all. See this post for further instructions : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194194/6868843